# Filling columns of a 2D array with the same number

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a piece of code that will show this at the end

```
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5
```

But what I've written shows this instead

```
1 1 1 1 1
2 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0
```

Here's the code I've written

```
int col, lig, test;
col = 0;
test = 0;
for (lig = mat.GetLowerBound(0); lig <= mat.GetUpperBound(0); lig++)
{
    mat[lig, col] = 1 + test++;
}
for (col = mat.GetLowerBound(0) + 1; col <= mat.GetUpperBound(0); col++)
{
    mat[0, col] = mat[0, col] + 1;
}
```

I've tried multiple things but none of them worked, what can I modify so that it gives the result I'm trying to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

- You are checking the bounds of the array in dimension `0` for the second loop (for `col`), but using `col` in dimension 1 of the array: you should be using `GetLowerBound(1)` and `GetUpperBound(1)` instead. This isn't an issue here because you have a square array, but you should be aware.
- You need to use a *nested* loop over the row and column, not two separate j loops. Your code is doing what you tell it to:

  - In the first loop you're setting `mat[lig, col]` but `col` is zero so you only set values in the first column. By declaring `lig` and `col` **in** the loops (see my code below) you can avoid this mistake.
  - In the second loop you're setting `mat[0, col]` which will only change values in the first row.
  - Additionally, you're starting the second loop at `mat.GetLowerBound(0) + 1` which will miss the first element out. Presumably you did this on purpose because it set the element at (0,0) to 2.

The code you need is:

```
int test = 0;
for ( int lig = mat.GetLowerBound(0); lig <= mat.GetUpperBound(0); lig++ )
{
    test++;

    for ( int col = mat.GetLowerBound(1); col <= mat.GetUpperBound(1); col++ )
        mat[lig, col] = test;
}
```

---

You can further simplify this by noting that `test` is always `lig + 1` and eliminate `test` altogether:

```
for ( int lig = mat.GetLowerBound(0); lig <= mat.GetUpperBound(0); lig++ )
{
    for ( int col = mat.GetLowerBound(1); col <= mat.GetUpperBound(1); col++ )
        mat[lig, col] = lig + 1;
}
```